# Converting multiple xmls in 1 file to a csv

Tags: perl

I have a text file that contains over multiple xmls that look like this:

```
<queryResponse><entity><devicesDTO><clearedAlarms>1</clearedAlarms><warningAlarms>0</warningAlarms></devicesDTO></entity></queryResponse>
<queryResponse><entity><devicesDTO><clearedAlarms>2</clearedAlarms><warningAlarms>2</warningAlarms></devicesDTO></entity></queryResponse>
```

I would like to convert each line to a csv:

```
clearedAlarms, warningAlarms
1, 0
2, 2
```

Here's what I have now that only enables me to parse a xml and output the csv. The file has actually changed now and I'm supposed to be reading a txt file that contains multiple xmls

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

#Elements, that I want see in my csv
my @Fields = qw{clearedAlarms warningAlarms};

open(my $out, '>', 'test.csv') or die "Output: $!\n";
print $out join(',', @Fields) . "\n";

my $xml = XMLin('test.xml', ForceArray => ['entity']);
foreach my $entity ( @{ $xml->{entity} } ) {
    print Dumper $entity;
}
foreach my $entity ( @{ $xml->{entity} } ) {
    print $out join( ',', @{ $entity->{devicesDTO} }{@Fields} ) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: When a module's documentation tells you not to use the module, don't use the module

Answer (score 2):

It's the origin of the Perl slogan: “There's More Than One Way To Do It!”   If you don't want to use xml module ( as you mentioned The file has actually changed now and I'm supposed to be reading a txt file that contains multiple xmls) You can use https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Grep mdoule (Find matches to a pattern in a series of files and related functions) for file operations.and https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS (https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) This module provides more  function related to csv operation which you can utilise as per your requirements.

> fmap BLOCK LIST
> Performs a map operation on the files in LIST, using BLOCK as the mapping function. The results from BLOCK will be appended to the list that is returned at the end of the call.

> csv This is a high-level function that aims at simple (user) interfaces. This can be used to read/parse a CSV file or stream (the default behavior) or to produce a file or write to a stream (define the out attribute).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Grep qw(fmap);
use Text::CSV_XS qw( csv );
use Data::Dumper;

my $data;
my $csv_file='test_file.csv';

# my @result  = fmap { <block> } file_name; 
# replace *DATA with your file path.
# checking the pattern and extracting value
# pushing values to array to create array of array
fmap { (/<clearedAlarms>(.*?)<\/clearedAlarms><warningAlarms>(.*?)<\/warningAlarms>/ ? push(@$data,[$1,$2]) : () ) } *DATA;

if (@$data) {
  # Write array of arrays as csv file
  csv (in => $data, out => $csv_file, sep_char=> ",", headers => [qw( clearedAlarms warningAlarms )]);   
} else {
  print "\n data not found (provide proper message)\n";
}

__DATA__
<queryResponse><entity><devicesDTO><clearedAlarms>1</clearedAlarms><warningAlarms>0</warningAlarms></devicesDTO></entity></queryResponse>
<queryResponse><entity><devicesDTO><clearedAlarms>2</clearedAlarms><warningAlarms>2</warningAlarms></devicesDTO></entity></queryResponse>
```

> Ouput (if you open $csv_file file)

```
clearedAlarms,warningAlarms
1,0
2,2
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the simplicity of the XML schema, this easier to do with AnyData

For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# This script converts a XML file to CSV format.

# Load the AnyData XML to CSV conversion modules
use XML::Parser;
use XML::Twig;
use AnyData;

my $input_xml = "test.xml";
my $output_csv = "test.csv";


$flags->{record_tag} = 'ITEM';
adConvert( 'XML', $input_xml, 'CSV', $output_csv, $flags );
```

Would convert your data structure (XML) into:

```
clearedAlarms, warningAlarms
1, 0
2, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file structure is always the same, you indeed don't need an XML parser. But you don't need anything else either. You can treat that input file like a slightly more complex CSV file that has weird delimiters.

[`split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) uses a *pattern* to turn a string into a list of strings. By default it will eat the delimiter match, so this disappear. We can use a pattern that looks like an XML tag as the pattern. Note how I am using `qr//` with a delimiter that isn't the slash `/` to make this more readable, because it avoids escaping the optional slash `/` in the closing tag.

```
split qr{</?[^>]+>}, '<foo>123</foo>';
```

This will produce a data structure that looks like this (using [Data::Printer](https://p3rl.org/Data::Printer) to produce the output):

```
[
    [0] "",
    [2] 123
]
```

The first element is an empty string, which denotes the lack of any other characters before the first match of the delimiter pattern. We need to filter these out. That's easily done with [`grep`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

```
grep { $_ ne q{} } split qr{</?[^>]+>}, '<foo>123</foo>';
```

Now our output is nice and clean.

```
[
    [0] 123
]
```

All we now need to do is apply this to a full file. Since our data only contains a couple of numbers, there is no need to use Text::CSV in this case.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say join ',', grep { $_ ne q{} } split qr{</?[^>]+>};
}

__DATA__
<queryResponse><entity><devicesDTO><clearedAlarms>1</clearedAlarms><warningAlarms>0</warningAlarms></devicesDTO></entity></queryResponse>
<queryResponse><entity><devicesDTO><clearedAlarms>2</clearedAlarms><warningAlarms>2</warningAlarms></devicesDTO></entity></queryResponse>
```

Please keep in mind that we can use a pattern match here because we don't actually parse the XML. Do not use regular expressions if you want to do any real XML parsing!